# Swift 5 : Convert Array/Dictionary to JSON format

Tags: arrays, json, swift, dictionary

I have an data which as given below:

```
[
  (ingredient_item: "Oil", ingredient_item_id: "1", ingredient_qty: "1", ingredient_unit_id: "Tsp", ingredient_remark: ""), 
  (ingredient_item: "Saffron", ingredient_item_id: "2", ingredient_qty: "2", ingredient_unit_id: "Tsp", ingredient_remark: ""), 
  (ingredient_item: "Rice", ingredient_item_id: "3", ingredient_qty: "2", ingredient_unit_id: "Cup", ingredient_remark: "")
]
```

and the required output is in the following form:

```
ingredients
[
 {
  ingredient_item:chicken,
  ingredient_item_id:1,
  ingredient_qty:2,
  ingredient_unit_id:2,
  ingredient_remark:abcd
 },
 {
  ingredient_item:salt,
  ingredient_item_id:2,
  ingredient_qty:2,
  ingredient_unit_id:2
  ingredient_remark:abcd
 }
]
```

Can anyone help me to solve this?

Comment: `required output` is not a valid `JSON`. Can you clarify whether you need it to be `JSON` or exactly like you specified?

Comment: I need exactly like what i specified.. I didn't understand what datatype it is. @user28434

Comment: Array of *what*? use `codable` or `serialization`

Comment: I used serialization but  I am getting an error `] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid type in JSON write (__SwiftValue)'` . @MojtabaHosseini

Comment: You are probably trying to serialize a custom object that is not possible automatically.

Comment: Unrelated but what are all the `ingredient_` prefixes for? Actually they are redundant and without them your data packages will shrink to half the size.

Comment: the api provided by the team insist so @vadian and they aint gonna change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a model and encode to it like;

```
let yourArray = [
  (ingredient_item: "Oil", ingredient_item_id: "1", ingredient_qty: "1", ingredient_unit_id: "Tsp", ingredient_remark: ""),
  (ingredient_item: "Saffron", ingredient_item_id: "2", ingredient_qty: "2", ingredient_unit_id: "Tsp", ingredient_remark: ""),
  (ingredient_item: "Rice", ingredient_item_id: "3", ingredient_qty: "2", ingredient_unit_id: "Cup", ingredient_remark: "")
]

struct Model: Encodable {
    var ingredient_item: String
    var ingredient_item_id: String
    var ingredient_qty: String
    var ingredient_unit_id: String
    var ingredient_remark: String
}

let arr = yourArray.map({ Model(ingredient_item: $0,
                          ingredient_item_id: $1,
                          ingredient_qty: $2,
                          ingredient_unit_id: $3,
                          ingredient_remark: $4)})

let jsonData = try! JSONEncoder().encode(arr)
let jsonString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8)
```

Comment: At `Model` I am getting an error `Use of unresolved identifier 'Model'`

Comment: You should create a model. Check the edited answer above.

Comment: While passing the jsonString as parameter using Alamofire, the parameter is `Optional("[{\"method_stage\":\"0\",\"method_description\":\"This is method 1\"}]")` how can remove this  " \ " from it??

Comment: `\"`specifies the escaping character (string inside string). So if you have a inline json string, it is already included.

Comment: is there any way to remove the slash character alone from it?